# Invoice List Running Balance based on date and Account

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and have made a UserForm that Displays a complete list of Invoices from Worksheets("InvoiceListIncome") using a ListBox control, the Worksheet has 13 Columns and Thousands of rows, an example image below;
[image]
The problem I'm having is the Balance Row Range("InvoiceListIncome_Balance")" displays the balance of each Invoice individual, what I need is a running balance starting from the first invoice Range("InvoiceListIncome_Date") so with each Transaction it Adds up the Current + all previous invoices for that account.

The Macro I'm currently using is;

```
Range("InvoiceListIncome_Balance").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1])-SUM(RC[-2])"
```

which simply subtracts whats Paid in Column F from Item Price in Column G, but I cant seem to figure out how to add all previous balances by date, I can either get it to Sum the complete Range with the Customers account as the criteria or just the activerow.

I have been running circles trying to figure this out for days now, any help would be muchly appreciated, thanks.

Here is an example of what I need;
[image]

Comment: Can you try to explain with some more concrete details?  This sounds like something I could help with, with a push in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Ronnie, I've added an example of what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Account, Price, and Paid in columns A, D, and E, respectively, with your first row of data in row 2, try the following formula in row 2:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A2,$A2,$E$2:$E2)-SUMIF($A$2:$A2,$A2,$D$2:$D2)
```

Copy the formula down the column.  This assumes that your data is sorted in increasing chronological order as you show.

Also, if this formula is working, you have the wrong sign on the 4th row from the bottom of the column that you want????

Comment: Thank you so much Ronny, worked perfect!, just replaced A, D & E with A, E & F and it worked exactly as I envisioned it, I've done my head in over the past few weeks trying to figure this out, again thank you greatly for your help muchly appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want a running total, so you want to incorporate the balance of row (n-1) when calculating the balance for row n.

Based on your 1st picture, make the following changes:

- formula in G2: `=F2-E2`
- formula in G3: `=G2+F3-E3`
- copy formula from G3 down to the end of the list; the last value is your current balance

**edit**

sorry ... I seem to have overlooked the break-on-account condition. Well that makes it even easier as there is only one formula you need all the way down ....

to break on customer (provided the customer column is sorted) you would use the following formula

- formula in G2: `=IF(A2=A1,G1+F2-E2,F2-E2)`
- copy formula from G2 down to the end of the list

(*if this.account = previous.account then calculate.running.total else create.new.balance*)

This will work as long as your first customers' name is <> "Account" :-)

Comment: That doesn't work as it assumes there is only 1 customer and adds all the Invoices up rather than per individual customer.

Comment: From what I can see it still adds the Balances up individually rather than summing all previous invoices for that account and im not sure how or where to add the code you provided at the bottom;
(if this.account = previous.account then calculate.running.total else create.new.balance)

Thanks a heap for your help so far ;)

Comment: the code at the bottom just illustrates what the =IF(...) is doing - you don't enter it anywhere